# Calculating Maaser Kesafim and living expenses

Tags: maaser-tithes

When calculating one's maaser kesafim obligation the mainstream position seems to be that the maaser should be taken from one's net income representing gross income minus statutory deductions and a few limited other, [example](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/maaser-deductibles).  There is a minority opinion represented by the Chofetz Chaim in Ahavat Chesed that one may also deduct living expenses, though no qualification is given.  Are there other's who elaborate on this position?

Comment: The position is also mention in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 34.4

Comment: Only in some version of the Kitzur, other versions omit it.